# How to configure Hibernate Db connection settings in JAVA based spring config

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, orm

Currently I am moving my beans creation and config settings from XML based to JAVA based spring config. I am stuck with moving db settings? How can I write these hibernate db settings in JAVA based config file?

```
<bean
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <value>
            hibernate.connection.driver_class=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
            hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:mysql://url
            hibernate.connection.username=username
            hibernate.connection.password=password
            hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect
            hibernate.show_sql=false
            </value>

    </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.test" />

</bean>


<tx:annotation-driven />

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true" />
```

I have added Transaction details. I am getting this exception:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.hibernate.context.spi.CurrentSessionContext

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the config. I have also added transaction management features which you will definately need in the final solution.

```
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DbConfig{

@Bean
public DataSource getDatasource() {

        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://url");
        dataSource.setUsername("username");
        dataSource.setPassword("password");

        return dataSource;
    }

@Bean
public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() throws IOException{

LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
 sessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.test");

//getHibernateProperties method is a private method 

  sessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(getHibernateProperties());
    sessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(getDatasource());
    sessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();

    return sessionFactoryBean.getObject();
}

@Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager getTransactionManager() throws IOException{
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setSessionFactory(getSessionFactory());

        return transactionManager;
   }


private static Properties getHibernateProperties() {

        Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
        hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect");
        hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.show_sql", false);
        // other properties

        return hibernateProperties;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks :) Let me check and get back

Comment: I am getting NoClassDefFound exception. I have updated the question with few more details and exception. Can you please help?

Comment: I am using hibernate 3. Can you please pass on the imports?

Comment: added the imports

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer isn't full. This code helped me out:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = {массив пакетов с классами @Component, @Service, @Repository, @Controller})
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.jdev.blog.admin.crud.repositories", entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactory")
public class ApplicationConfiguration { 
   @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD));

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistenceProvider.class);

        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(hibProperties());

        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    private Properties hibProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT, env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT));
        properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL, env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL));
        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import com.sda.hibernate.associations.one_to_many_bi.Child;
import com.sda.hibernate.associations.one_to_many_bi.Parent;
import com.sda.hibernate.associations.one_to_many_uni.Daughter;
import com.sda.hibernate.associations.one_to_many_uni.Mother;
import com.sda.hibernate.associations.one_to_many_uni_join.Father;
import com.sda.hibernate.associations.one_to_many_uni_join.Son;
import com.sda.hibernate.types.Player;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Environment;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;

import java.util.Properties;

public class HibernateUtil {

    // get a session factory
    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        Configuration configuration = createConfig();

        ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
            .applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();

        return configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
    }

    private static Configuration createConfig() {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();

        Properties settings = new Properties();
        settings.put(Environment.DRIVER, "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        settings.put(Environment.URL, "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernate?serverTimezone=UTC");
        settings.put(Environment.USER, "root");
        settings.put(Environment.PASS, "root");
        settings.put(Environment.DIALECT, "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect");
        settings.put(Environment.SHOW_SQL, "true");
        settings.put(Environment.CURRENT_SESSION_CONTEXT_CLASS, "thread");
        settings.put(Environment.HBM2DDL_AUTO, "create-drop");

        configuration.setProperties(settings);

        // add annotated classes
        configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Player.class);
        configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Mother.class);
        configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Daughter.class);
        configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Father.class);
        configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Son.class);
        configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Child.class);
        configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Parent.class);

        return configuration;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.